# GitHub API3 Delete Access Token

Tags: oauth, github-api

I am making a form that allows users to agree to some conditions before a pull request can be merged into the core of a project.  To provide proof of ownership for the GitHub account, the user is required to give the my website read-only access to their GitHub account, using the GitHub API.

I would like to provide "revoke access" functionality to users - I don't actually want access to their account, it is just a good way for me to verify account ownership.

I know that the user is able to revoke application access via the [GitHub Applications](https://github.com/settings/applications) settings page, but I would like to streamline this if possible. I've looked through the GitHub APIv3 documentation, but have not seen anything that allows one to request that GitHub revokes an access_token.

**Question**:

Is it possible to programatically revoke my application's access_token?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the [GitHub OAuth Authorizations API](https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth_authorizations/#delete-an-authorization), they list the ability to delete an authorization using "DELETE /authorizations/:id"

Comment: When you do a "GET /authorizations", each authorization has an ID associated with it. That's what you use for :ID

Comment: i am not able to revoke authorisation , can you please help me to solve it . .

Comment: I'm going to need a little more to go on. What are you doing? What error are you getting?

Comment: thanks for response .. i tried this to get id                                             
    NSString * url = @"https://api.github.com/authorizations";           NSMutableURLRequest *request2 = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:gistCreateURLString2]]; then i sent a request ... but i am not getting any error , response data giving following .... "documentation_url" = "http://developer.github.com/v3";
    message = "Not Found";

Comment: i think there some thing wrong in my url , what i have to append with that to get id , then i can pass this id , to revoke access token

Comment: i tried this url also : https://api.github.com/authorizations?client_id=7a1e0a1fd6aaabdd2db9

Comment: This api has been deprecated: https://developer.github.com/changes/2020-02-14-deprecating-oauth-auth-endpoint/. The proper endpoint seems to be https://developer.github.com/v3/apps/oauth_applications/#delete-an-app-token

Comment: Juraj were you able to make this work? I keep getting a 422 when following the docs.

Answer (score 4):

You can revoke an auth token:

> Revoke an authorization for an application
>
> OAuth application owners can also revoke a single token for an OAuth
>   application. You must use Basic Authentication for this method, where
>   the username is the OAuth application client_id and the password is
>   its client_secret.
>
> DELETE /applications/:client_id/tokens/:access_token

The [documentation](https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth_authorizations/#get-or-create-an-authorization-for-a-specific-app) is correct; I've verified this works.

Comment: Note that this doesn't revoke the granted permission, however.  If the application wants to come along and request it again, it'll be given.

Comment: This seems to be the proper endpoint: https://developer.github.com/changes/2020-02-14-deprecating-oauth-auth-endpoint: https://developer.github.com/v3/apps/oauth_applications/#delete-an-app-token

Answer (score 1):

i know it's late , but i hope this will help somebody else ,

```
   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.github.com/applications/%@/tokens/%@",GITHUB_CLIENT_ID,token]];

   NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
   NSString *theUsername = GITHUB_CLIENT_ID;
   NSString *thePassword = GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET;

   [request addValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Basic %@",[self base64forData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@",theUsername,thePassword] dataUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
   [request setHTTPMethod:@"DELETE"];
   [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

   NSError *error = nil;
   NSURLResponse *response;

   [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];



- (NSString*)base64forData:(NSData*)theData
{
    const uint8_t* input = (const uint8_t*)[theData bytes];
    NSInteger length = [theData length];

    static char table[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=";

    NSMutableData* data = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:((length + 2) / 3) * 4];
    uint8_t* output = (uint8_t*)data.mutableBytes;

    NSInteger i;
    for (i=0; i < length; i += 3) {
        NSInteger value = 0;
        NSInteger j;
        for (j = i; j < (i + 3); j++) {
            value <<= 8;

            if (j < length) {
                value |= (0xFF & input[j]);
            }
        }

        NSInteger theIndex = (i / 3) * 4;
        output[theIndex + 0] =                    table[(value >> 18) & 0x3F];
        output[theIndex + 1] =                    table[(value >> 12) & 0x3F];
        output[theIndex + 2] = (i + 1) < length ? table[(value >> 6)  & 0x3F] : '=';
        output[theIndex + 3] = (i + 2) < length ? table[(value >> 0)  & 0x3F] : '=';
    }

    return [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding] autorelease];
}
```

Comment: Can you please send me how to do with postman? either screenshot will be helpful.